# Change text by click and remembering answer for further compare

Tags: android

Got the app which guessed the person by comparing answer on the question. The app has question and button (y/n).
  How I can save answer for further compare and change question to the next? Want to do this on the only activity. App's screenshot below. 
[Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldB4f.jpg)
  Button will constantly be on this position, changes only question and after change, answers must save in different bool-variables.

Comment: Then you should have used set variables like a string array and a boolean array for your answers only one activity for all!

Comment: Show us some code, so we can help you. Also do you want to remember answer after app is closed? or only when you are on screen

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). **Research, try something, add your code & point your problem.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a `ArrayList` which contains all the question and will be displayed index by index. Such as:

```
 int questionNo = 0; //Should be class variable
 ArrayList<String> questionList = new ArrayList<>();
  btnNext.setOnCLick(.....
     onCLick(){
         String question = questionList.get(questionNo);
         questionNo++;
     }
```

and on saving of all answer, you can use `ArrayList` as well, Like::

```
   ArrayList<String> answers= new ArrayList<>();
   btnNext.setOnCLick(.....
     onCLick(){
         String question = questionList.get(questionNo);
         questionNo++;
         answers.add("Your answer");
     }
```

by above code , you will have access to all answer in "answers" according to position of question in questionList.

Thanks and let me know if some thing need more to know.

**EDITED:**

**Here is your activity::**

```
 public class ThirdActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<>();

String optionSelected="";

int questionNo=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);


    questions.add("Question A");
    questions.add("Question B");
    questions.add("Question C");
    questions.add("Question D");
    questions.add("Question E");
    questions.add("Question F");
    questions.add("Question G");
    questions.add("Question H");
    questions.add("Question I");
    questions.add("Question J");
    questions.add("Question K");

    final TextView questionText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);
    questionText.setText(questions.get(questionNo++));

    final RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            switch (checkedId)
            {
                case R.id.yesButton:
                    optionSelected="yes";
                    break;
                case R.id.noButton:
                    optionSelected="no";
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    final Button nextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if(questionNo==questions.size()-1)
            {
                nextButton.setText("Print All");
                questionText.setText(questions.get(questionNo++));
                answers.add(optionSelected);
                optionSelected="";
                radioGroup.clearCheck();
            }
            if(questionNo<questions.size()){
                questionText.setText(questions.get(questionNo++));
                answers.add(optionSelected);
                optionSelected="";
                radioGroup.clearCheck();
            }
            else{
                Log.d("Print All",answers+" ");
            }
        }
    });


}
 }
```

**and here is xml file::**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/question"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

  <RadioGroup
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
   android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
   <RadioButton
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/yesButton"
       android:text="Yes"/>
   <RadioButton
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/noButton"
       android:text="No"/>
 </RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="next"
    android:id="@+id/next"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks and now let me know if need to know more.

Comment: Well, how the button must change question, if we call method once, i would to post code, have i do it here?

Comment: int size = questionsList.size();
        final boolean []checking = new boolean[size];
        final int[] count = {0};
        buttonNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               // setContentView(R.layout.activity_questions);
                question = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.unfillQuestion);
                question.setText((CharSequence)questionsList);
                checking[count[0]] = false;
                count[0]++;
            }
        });